# Java-Read from custom file extension issue

Tags: java, file

```
String blocks[][] = null;
        int linecount = 0;
        String oneL;
        File lvl = new File("res/1.mpl");

        try {
            BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(lvl)));
            while((oneL = rdr.readLine()) != null){
                String[] line =oneL.split(".");
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length;i++){
                blocks[i][linecount] = line[i];
                System.out.println(line[i]);
            }
            ++linecount;
            }
            rdr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am trying to read stuff from a custom file and then pass it to a multidimensional array. This part of code does not get excecuted. Any help?

This part causes everything to fail silently :

```
blocks[i][linecount] = line[i];
```

Comment: Fail how? With an exception? A failed test case?

Comment: When you asked any question to other person then make sure he/she understand your question properly.In this question you have just mentioned your program fail silently at some point.Better to mentioned the output like error,Exception,or Not getting any output(In this question you are not getting any output-As I understand...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print the line.length it will be zero.So first you should use split("\."),and then initialize the block with the proper size.I have just initialize with line.length.You can modify.

```
 while((oneL = rdr.readLine()) != null){
                String[] line =oneL.split("\\.");
                blocks=new String[line.length][line.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length;i++){
                blocks[i][linecount] = line[i];
                System.out.println(line[i]);

            }
            ++linecount;
        }
```

Comment: ah.... I forgot the special chars again -_-

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized `blocks`; by the time you get to that line, it is still `null`.

Comment: I added this line : blocks = new String[totalx][totaly]; anyway , this is the place where I set the values. totalx / totaly are the max sizes for the array

Comment: And you're still getting the problem? When you say it "fails silently," how silent are we talking?